# How do I operate on this list elegantly?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

```
calibData = { {200, 10}, {100, 20} }

MapAt[N, MapAt[Log10, calibData, {;; , 1}], {;; , 1}]
```

I want to apply a base 10 Log to the first element of each tuple.  Then the output should be displayed as a floating point number.

This bit of code does the job, but it is ugly and its hard to understand what it is doing.  Is there a better way of completing this task?

Comment: This is using the solution of that post.  I think this was a new issue I had.  The motivation behind the post was to understand functional style programming to a greater extent.

Comment: Have no idea why this post got downvoted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large amount of `calibData`, then preserving [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array) can greatly improve speed. Convert it all to `Reals` and then apply logarithm.

```
calibData = 10 RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {10^6, 2}];

Transpose @ {Log10 @ #[[1]], #[[2]]} &@ Transpose @ N @ calibData; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.098568, Null} *)

Transpose @ {Log10 @ N @ calibData[[All, 1]], N @ calibData[[All, 2]]}; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.106482, Null} *)

MapAt[Log10, N@calibData, {All, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.525485, Null} *)
```

The second components of `calibData` get converted to `Real` in this process.  If you need them to be integers, you might use `Round` if the integers are not too large.  Otherwise, you can hope that the performance with unpacked arrays is acceptable.

Compared with unpacked:

```
Transpose @ {Log10 @ N @ calibData[[All, 1]], calibData[[All, 2]]}; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.369981, Null} *)

MapAt[N @ Log10[#] &, calibData, {All, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {8.740113, Null} *)
```

The arrays will be unpacked in these cases because the numbers are not all the same type (some `Real`, some `Integer`).

Answer (score 2):

This question has probably been asked here before, or something similar. I can't find it yet but try this:

```
MapAt[N@Log10[#] &, calibData, {All, 1}]
```

OR via pattern-matching:

```
calibData /. {x_, y_} :> {N@Log10[x], y}
```

Using `Apply`:

```
{N @ Log10 @ #1, #2} & @@@ calibData
```